# Is this an optimal way for composing optional data structures into a value object?

Tags: java, data-structures, java-8

I have a value object (`Test2`) which will hold a number of optional data structures (implementations of `PropertySet`). I cannot compose all of them into `Test2` because there will be a lot of variants and implementing all the permutations would lead to a proliferation of classes. I came up with the following solution:

```
public class Test2
{

    static interface PropertySet
    {

    }

    static class LocationInfo implements PropertySet
    {
        String lat;
        String lng;

        public LocationInfo(String lat, String lng)
        {
            this.lat = lat;
            this.lng = lng;
        }

    }

    private Map<Class<? extends PropertySet>, PropertySet> propertySets = new HashMap<>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T extends PropertySet> T fetchPropertySet(Class<? extends T> propertySetType)
    {
        T result = (T) propertySets.get(propertySetType);
        return result;
    }

    public LocationInfo getLocationInfo()
    {
        return this.<LocationInfo> fetchPropertySet(LocationInfo.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test2 test = new Test2();
        test.propertySets.put(LocationInfo.class, new LocationInfo("1", "1"));

        LocationInfo locationInfo = test.<LocationInfo> fetchPropertySet(LocationInfo.class);
        System.out.println(locationInfo.lat + ", " + locationInfo.lng);

        LocationInfo locationInfo2 = test.getLocationInfo();
        System.out.println(locationInfo2.lat + ", " + locationInfo2.lng);
    }
}
```

My question is whether this solution is considered as a good practice for this kind of problem or not?

**Note** that I cannot use external libraries like *Guava* but java 8 is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a type with a lot of optional properties, using a map is a sufficient way. However, its questionable that you are using the *type* of a property as the key. Compare with ordinary fields/ properties which are distinguished by name and *have* a type, i.e. where you can have multiple properties of the same type. Your example of `LocationInfo` shows that. It represents a location without a particular meaning. It’s perfectly imaginable that there might be an entity having two properties of type `LocationInfo`, e.g. `startLocation` and `endLocation`.

So you should not mix up the use of a type for defining a property and the type representing a value. That said, there is no reason for that `interface PropertySet`. It adds no value to the types but only an unnecessary constraint.

To fix that, use a key holding both, name and type of a property:

```
public class Test2
{
    static class LocationInfo
    {
        String lat;
        String lng;

        public LocationInfo(String lat, String lng)
        {
            this.lat = lat;
            this.lng = lng;
        }
    }

    private static final class PropKey {
        final Class<?> type;
        final String name;

        public PropKey(Class<?> type, String name) {
            this.type = Objects.requireNonNull(type);
            this.name = Objects.requireNonNull(name);
        }
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(name, type);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if(obj==this) return true;
            if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof PropKey)) return false;
            final PropKey other = (PropKey) obj;
            return type==other.type && name.equals(other.name);
        }
    }
    private final Map<PropKey, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> T fetchProperty(Class<T> type, String name)
    {
        return type.cast(properties.get(new PropKey(type, name)));
    }
    // your decision whether this should be public
    <T> void putProperty(Class<T> type, String name, T value)
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull(value);
        properties.put(new PropKey(type, name), value);
    }

    public LocationInfo getPosition()
    {
        return fetchProperty(LocationInfo.class, "position");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test2 test = new Test2();
        test.putProperty(LocationInfo.class, "position", new LocationInfo("1", "1"));

        LocationInfo locationInfo = test.fetchProperty(LocationInfo.class, "position");
        System.out.println(locationInfo.lat + ", " + locationInfo.lng);

        LocationInfo locationInfo2 = test.getPosition();
        System.out.println(locationInfo2.lat + ", " + locationInfo2.lng);

        test.putProperty(String.class, "debugInfo", "hello world");
        System.out.println(test.fetchProperty(String.class, "debugInfo"));
    }
}
```

As already hinted, there shouldn’t be a tight connection between the entity and the types of its properties, so you may turn the `LocationInfo` class into a top level type for all use cases incorporating a latitude/longitude pair. It’s strongly recommended to use the immutable value type pattern for this class as with all property types you are going to store in the map as the generic method for putting them is incapable of creating defensive copies to protect against false sharing of mutable objects between multiple instances of `Test2`.

Another thing to consider, since the properties are optional, the getter methods may return an `Optional<PropertyType>` instead of encoding the absence of a property using `null`.

Comment: I see your point with multiple instances. As this will be part of an MVP I'm going to do it the simplest way possible. The comment about the `Optional` is very good indeed thanks for pointing that out. I've not yet got used to the new java features. :)

Comment: By the way, note how `type.cast(…)` makes the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Guava has a [ClassToInstanceMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v18.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ClassToInstanceMap.html) that you can use, that stores a map of class -> instance of that class:

```
ClassToInstanceMap<PropertySet> map = MutableClassToInstanceMap.create();
map.putInstance(LocationInfo.class, new LocationInfo("1", "1"));

LocationInfo li = map.getInstance(LocationInfo.class);
```

Comment: Can you put a very simple example in your answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

```
public <T extends PropertySet> T fetchPropertySet(Class<T> propertySetType)
```

(eleminate wildcards)

This way you don't need to explicitly specify the generics argument, and you may not need a wrapper such as `getLocationInfo`. And you can still use the returned `T` instance as T's superclass.

Some questions about your intentions: will you need multiple instances of the same class? What do you do about subclasses?  Superclasses? As it stands now, each class will have its own instance. You may need to have single instance of most derived class available for all its superclasses (or some of its superclasses).

Comment: There will be only one instance of a class and there are no plans for subclasses. This is basically for grouped data composition.